# prove the nomalizer $N(H)$ of the subgroup $H$ in $G$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need some help on the following question.

For an arbitrary subgroup $H$ of the group $G$, the normalizer of $H$ in $G$ is the set $N(H) = \{x \in G \mid xHx^{-1} = H\}.$ Any help??

Comment: You need to show that $H$ is closed under inverses and the group multiplication. Inverses involves monkeying with $xHx^{-1}=H$, and complements should be pretty straightforward if you recall that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}.$

Comment: If you prove $N(H)\subseteq G$ then you only have to prove it is a subgroup. That is $e\in N(H)$, and that for all $g,h\in N(H)$, $g*h^{-1}\in N(H)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $x,y \in N(H)$ you should prove that their product $xy$ is also in $N(H)$, that is, $xyH(xy)^{-1} = H$.

But $xyH(xy)^{-1} = x(yHy^{-1})x^{-1} = xHx^{-1} = H$. The first equality holds because $y \in N(H)$ and the second, because $x \in N(H)$.

Also, the group unity $e$ should be in $N(H)$. But that is easy, since $eHe^{-1} = eHe = H$.

The last thing is to prove that given $x \in N(H)$, then its inverse $x^{-1}$ is also in $N(H)$. So, we should prove that $x^{-1}Hx = H$. But $x^{-1}Hx = x^{-1}(xHx^{-1})x = H$.

Comment: what about the inverse element??

Comment: Of course! I'm sorry! Just edited to put the inverse maths on my original answer.

Comment: By subgroup test, it's enough to show that products and inverses stay in $N(H)$. No need to check the identity.

Comment: Indeed. But if you want to shorten the argument even more, you can show that given $x,y \in N(H)$ their product $xy^{-1}$ is still in $N(H)$. From that we get identity and inverses.

Answer (score 1):

We'll use the one-step subgroup test to show $N(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$.

First, we see that $N(H)$ is nonempty since for any $h \in H$, $ehe^{-1} =h \in H$.

Now if $x, y, \in N(H)$ and $h \in H$, then 
$$(xy^{-1})h(xy^{-1})^{-1}=xy^{-1}hyx^{-1}$$

Since $y \in N(H)$, $y^{-1}hy \in H$ and so $y^{-1}hy=h_2$, for some $h_2 \in H$. So, $xy^{-1}hyx^{-1} =xh_2x^{-1}$.

Since $x \in N(H)$, $xh_2x^{-1} \in H$.

So, $xy^{-1} \in N(H)$ and thus $N(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$, $N(H) \le G$.